# Reference cell in a query in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZupYqXhA-_ZSfuOUN70YuQnC9DUw7PUlrzv117knJ-I

That's a link to the file in which it is not working!   If you open it, go to sheet named "My query stinks".

The sheet called deposits has data like this in columns A (date), B (description), and C (amount):

6/29/2016   Deposit     480

6/24/2016   Deposit     359.61

8/8/2016    Deposit     11.11

The sheet "My Query Stinks" has data in columns A (check number), B (empty) and C (amount):

1000000044      480

1000000045      359.61

201631212301237     11.11

In Column B on My Query Stinks, I want to enter a query.  Here's what I'm trying: =query(Deposits!A2:C,"select A where C ='"&  C4 &"'")  For some reason, it returns #N/A Error Query completed with an empty output.  I want it to find that 11.11 (the value in C4) matches 11.11 over on Deposits and return the date.

EDIT 1/15/2020: Updated the link to the Google sheets file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've ended up with too many quotes in your formula. The following simplified version seems to work.

```
=query(Deposits!A2:C,"select A where C = "&C4)
```

Because of an extra set of quotes in the formula, I believe your original version ends up treating C4 as a text value instead of a cell address.

Additionally, it looks like that element opens with `'"` and then closes with `"'"` - so it's not balanced. I've had problems with auto-quoting like this in similar scenarios, especially on editing.

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Tom, That did indeed work.  Now, another mystery.  When I instead look at column B (which contains check numbers), it

Comment: Tom, That did indeed work. Now, another mystery. When I instead look at column B (which contains check numbers), it returns, "Error
Query completed with an empty output."  I have updated the spreadsheet that is linked above to show the issue.

Comment: I think you meant `=query(Deposits!A:C,"select A where C =" &  C2)` & if the response above works please accept the answer.